# Creating and name many sub df using df.loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe with product id, location were the product was sold, and team that sold a given product in the area.

I want to create a subdataframe for each team as follows:

```
team = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']  
subdf_name = ['r', 'b', 'o' , 'bl']
```

I tried :

```
def newdf (subdf, team_id):
    subdf = df.loc [df ['Team'] == team_id , ['product_id', 'x', 'y', 'Team']]
    return subdf 

for i,j in zip (subdf_name, team_id) : 
        newdf (i,j)
```

however, when I call red team df (print (red), python reports that

> NameError: name 'red' is not defined

currently working with python 3.6

thanks in advance for your collaboration

Comment: Perhaps change `Team` to `team` - does case matter? Or should `team_id` be `team` in the zip argument? Or are `Team` and `team_id` in reverse positions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses. The code in your example does not successfully run by itself.